# Automaticaly encode categorical data to numbers in Excel

Tags: excel, automation, data-science

I have data about cars and there are some columns containing categorical data: `Make` `Model` `Transmission`
I want to encode this data to numbers. For example:

```
Make:          

BMW     ->     0
Audi           0.25
FIAT           0.5
BMW            0
Nissan         1
FIAT           0.5
Audi           0.25
```

Since there is a lot of data in my sheet, is there a formula or function that could do this conversion **automatically** in Excel?

Comment: Hi, you could add an additional column that takes a `vlookup` from the table you provided in your question and pulls in the second column using the make. I know you ask specifically for automatically, but using a Table Formatting `CTRL` + `T` you can have this formula continue down as more data is added to the table.

Comment: manual , but fast >> Ctrl + H ( :